# C --> headers & variables

Tags: c, variables, header

Can the headers files in C include variables?

I am a beginner in programming; started with C, and I know the importance of precision especially in the first steps of the learning process

Comment: They can, but it is bad practice. Stick to function prototypes, extern declarations,  and types.

Comment: At the very least, see the first part of [How do I use `extern` to share variables between source files in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204).  You should stop your reading not later than the second 'invitation to stop' — the rest would be confusing to you now.

Answer (score 1):

Including files is done by the preprocessor before even attempting to compile the code and it simply does text replacement – it puts the contents of the included file in the current unit that is going to be passed to the compiler. The compiler then sees the concatenated output and no `#include` directives at all.

With that said, technically you can include anything that is valid C code.

The good practice, however, is that only type definitions, `#define`s, function *declarations* (not *definitions*) and data *declarations* (not *definitions*) should be in a header. A function declaration is also called a prototype and merely specifies the function signature (its return type, name and parameters). Data declarations look very similar to data definitions, but have an `extern` storage class specifier and cannot be initialised:

```
extern int a; // declares "a" but does not define it
extern int a = 0; // defines "a" (initialisation requested), the extern is redundant
int a; // a tentative definition (no initialisation but "a" is zeroed)
```

Why is defining functions and data in a header file frowned upon? Because at link time, different units that have included the same header files will have the same symbols defined and the linker will see duplicate definitions of some symbols.

Also consider that a header is a kind of a "public" interface for the rest of the project (world?) and not every function that is defined in the source file needs to have a declaration there. It is perfectly fine to have internal types and `static` functions and data in the source file that never get exposed to the outside world.

Answer (score 0):

Basically in header files, we can declare variables point to be noted only declaration is allowed there, do not define 
let me clear.

```
int a=10;  // definition

extern int a; //declaration - it can be used in another file if u include this header file.
```

you can also define the macro and declare the functions in header file.

Comment: I think what you've said is correct, but it's very difficult to follow.

Comment: its simple man, just define variables in .c fie and declare them into .h

Answer (score 0):

Yes, header files may include variable declarations, but you generally don't want to do that because it will introduce maintenance headaches over time, especially as your code gets larger and more complex.  Ideally, functions should share information through parameters and return values, not by using such "global" data items.

There are times when you can't avoid it; I haven't done any embedded programming, but my understanding is that using globals is fairly common in that domain due to space and performance constraints.

Ideally, headers should be limited to the following:

- Macro definitions
- Type definitions
- Function declarations

But suppose you do create a header file with a variable declaration, like so:

```
/**
 * foo.h
 */

int foo;
```

and you have several source files that all include that header<sup>1</sup>:

```
/**
 * bar.c
 */
#include "foo.h"

void bar( void )
{
  printf( "foo = %d\n", foo );
}

/**
 * blurga.c
 */
#include "foo.h"

void blurga( void )
{
  foo = 10;
}

/**
 * main.c
 */
#include "foo.h"

int main( void )
{
  foo = 5;
  blurga();
  bar();
  return 0;
}
```

Each file will contain a declaration for `foo` at file scope (outside of any function).  Now you compile each file separately

```
gcc -c bar.c
gcc -c blurga.c
gcc -c main.c
```

giving you three object files - `bar.o`, `blurga.o`, and `main.o`.  Each of these object files will have their own unique copy of the `foo` variable.  However, when we build them into a single executable with

```
gcc -o foo main.o bar.o blurga.o
```

the linker is smart enough to realize that those separate declarations of `foo`  are meant to refer to the same object (the identifier `foo` has *external linkage* across those translation units).  So the `foo` that `main` initializes to `5` is the same `foo` that `blurga` sets to `10`, which is the same `foo` that `bar` prints out.

However, if you change the declaration of `foo` to

```
static int foo;
```

in `foo.h` and rebuild your files, then those separate declarations will *not* refer to the same object; they will remain three separate and distinct objects, such that the `foo` that `main` initializes is *not* the same `foo` that `blurga` sets to `10`, which is not the same `foo` that `bar` prints out (`foo` has *internal* linkage within each translation unit).

If you *must* use a global variable between several translation units, my preferred style is to declare the variable in the header file as `extern`<sup>2</sup>

```
/**
 * foo.h
 */
extern int foo;
```

and then define it in a corresponding .c file

```
/**
 * foo.c
 */
int foo;
```

so only a single object file creates an instance of `foo` and it's *crystal clear* that you intend for other translation units to make use of it.  The declaration in the header file isn't necessary for the variable to be shared (the `foo` identifier has external linkage by simple virtue of being declared in `foo.c` outside of any function and without the `static` keyword), but without it nobody else can be sure if you *meant* for it to be visible or if you just got sloppy.

**Edit**

Note that headers don't *have* to be included at the top of a file; you can be perverse and put an `#include` directive within a function body

```
void bar( void )
{
#include "foo.h"
   // do stuff with foo
}
```

such that `int foo;` will be local to the function, although that will likely earn you a beating from your fellow programmers. I got to maintain code where somebody did that, and after 25 years it still gives me nightmares.

---

<sup>1.  *Please* don't write code like this; it's only to illustrate the concept of linkage.

2.  The `extern` keyword tells the compiler that the object the identifier refers to is defined somewhere else.</sup>